# Selecting attributes using joins and select in rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a TopicRelation class which builds a relationship between two topics, using `source_topic_id` and `target_topic_id`. Here is the model:

```
class TopicRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :source_topic, class_name: 'Topic'
  belongs_to :target_topic, class_name: 'Topic'
end
```

I am trying to pull just the name of the source topic:

```
TopicRelation.joins(:source_topic, :target_topic)
  .where('source_topic_id=?', topic.id)
  .select('source_topics.name')
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
TopicRelation Load (113.7ms)  SELECT  source_topics.name FROM `topic_relations` INNER JOIN `topics` ON `topics`.`id` = `topic_relations`.`source_topic_id` INNER JOIN `topics` `target_topics_topic_relations` ON `target_topics_topic_relations`.`id` = `topic_relations`.`target_topic_id` WHERE (source_topic_id=1) LIMIT 10
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'source_topics.name' in 'field list': SELECT  source_topics.name FROM `topic_relations` INNER JOIN `topics` ON `topics`.`id` = `topic_relations`.`source_topic_id` INNER JOIN `topics` `target_topics_topic_relations` ON `target_topics_topic_relations`.`id` = `topic_relations`.`target_topic_id` WHERE (source_topic_id=1) LIMIT 10
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'source_topics.name' in 'field list': SELECT  source_topics.name FROM `topic_relations` INNER JOIN `topics` ON `topics`.`id` = `topic_relations`.`source_topic_id` INNER JOIN `topics` `target_topics_topic_relations` ON `target_topics_topic_relations`.`id` = `topic_relations`.`target_topic_id` WHERE (source_topic_id=1) LIMIT 10
```

**Is it possible to select the name for both `source_topic` and `target_topic` using this approach?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` use the name of the db table, which is likely `topics` in your case :

```
TopicRelation
  .joins('INNER JOIN topics target_topics ON topic_relations.target_topic_id = target_topics.id')
  .joins('INNER JOIN topics source_topics ON topic_relations.source_topic_id = source_topics.id')
  .where(source_topic: topic)
  .select('source_topics.name')
```

Also this will return a list of `TopicRelation`; If you want only the name of the topics, use the method [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) instead of `select`

Comment: Thanks. How would I select both source and target topic names using this approach? That is actually my real issue. Will update question.

Comment: @Abram I've edited my answer to use 2 joins with a separate table alias for each; Another solution would be to query `Topic` and join on `TopicRelation` which may be more readable, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Awesome yes that works. Not sure which approach would be better, but basically I will be looking for topic_relations that contain topic.id either as source or target id. So for this query I would add `where('source_topic_id=? OR target_topic_id=?', topic.id, topic.id)` to get what I want. Not sure if doing this via querying `Topic` would be more efficient?

Comment: You don't need joins for this: `TopicRelation.where('source_topic_id = :topic_id OR target_topic_id = :topic_id', {topic_id: topic.id})` . This will return a list of `TopicRelation`.

Comment: The reason I was doing the join was so that I could select the names from topic

Comment: Oh I get it, you want the name of all the topics related to a given topic (source or target) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88309/discussion-between-abram-and-baldrick).